# PHP Logout Problem?

Tags: php

when a user logouts from my web site they are logged out but on the logout page there username and the log out link and profile link are still visible on the logout page but not on any other pages.

All I want to know is how do I change the logout page so that the log out and proflie links and username are not displayed like the rest of the pages.

I'm using the same file where the links and username are displayed for every web page so what is the problem with the logout page?

Please leave a code sample to solve this problem if possible?

Comment: How do you maintain the state of bein logged in?

Answer (score 4):

If you’re using a session based authentication, make sure that you reset the `$_SESSION` variable as `session_destroy` does not do that. So:

```
session_destroy();
$_SESSION = array();
```

Answer (score 3):

I can only guess that your logic goes something like:

1. Display page header including logo, logout button and links;
2. Process the logout request.

I'm assuming that (1) will do things like display the right links and the username (if logged in). The point is that you're doing checks on being logged in before you log the user out. If so, just change the order:

1. Logout the user;
2. Display the page header, etc.

But it's hard to say definitively because I'm guessing at your page structure.

Answer (score 1):

it sounds like you include the code that displays the logout and profile links before you actually do the processing to log the user out. try seeing if you can rearrange the execution of your code so the include comes after youve already logged the user out.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION = array();
session_unset();
session_destroy();
header('login.php')
?>
```

Maybe you can try my method

Answer (score 0):

You can try things as per other answers ..

Or just create a logout.php .. which doesn't output anything so you just start the session, destroy all of the session or the required keys and then redirect the user to a logout_done.php which outputs, something like, You have been successfully logged out blah blah ..